# When are we graduating and Coming Out Of BETA?

Tags: discussion, beta

So its been long and stackexchange salesforce has been awesome so far.One thing I have failed to understand is why are we still in BETA.I see lot of questions posted and almost most of them get answered .My only concern has been not multiple answers .Most of questions have just one answer and I request lets make an attempt to increase this metrics but I don't see any reason we are in BETA yet .

I see the below metrics and looks awesome
http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/37589/salesforce

Let me know thoughts on what other contributors feel about the same ?

Comment: It was held up due to changes in the CSS requirements for the network in general and the need for an agreement between Salesforce and StackExchange around the styling. Apparently it *is* close.

Comment: @LaceySnr Thanks for the info .